# Is it possible to make big money using poker AI?

Tags: poker-tools

I've heard a lot of rumours about using poker AI to make a big amount of money on different poker networks. Are that just rumours or there is a real chance to be involved in such interesting business?

And the subquestion is did you ever heard about the companies developing poker AI? As a programmer and poker player I'm really interested in participating the development.

Comment: It's strictly against the terms of use of any site that you could trust enough to be worth the money. anything to the contrary is a scam and/or a scheme.

Comment: Yes, programs that are good enough can definitely end up earning a lot of money. The problem is just that making those programs good enough is quite difficult, as there are a lot of factors (position, range etc.) as well as your opponents, which you - in order to make maximum profit - have to assign a range to.

Comment: @Nij Wrong. Programs that play themselves are forbidden, programs that tell you what to do / what happened are not.

Comment: @Seth That is not correct.  Most site have limits to what a HUD is allowed to do.  Some gaming commissions flat out ban them.

Comment: @Paparazzi The popular poker sites are very liberal when it comes to enhancement programs. Only a few decide to drastically limit/straight up ban those enhancements.

Comment: @Seth could you provide a link to the T&Cs for "the popular poker sites" which allow software to be running at the same time as their client which makes or recommends decisions for the player? Check [here](https://www.pokerstars.uk/poker/room/prohibited/) for the PokerStars T&C section on software/tools for example, which explicitly prohibits (amongst other things) "Any tool or service that offers real-time commentary or advice on the current game state that goes beyond reporting data and statistics." - this would include any kind of AI tool which recommends an action to a player.

Comment: No you cannot make a big money using AI. It is just not good enough to beat people. There too many human variables in this game. Secondly, AI cannot stand against a maniac style. So if you keep 3betting and 4betting the AI bots will always fold as they are programmed in that way. You can try beating Neobot with a maniac style and will understand what I am talking about.

Comment: AIs are safe only in fixed limit poker games, AFAIK

Answer (score 1):

Most if not all sites have limits to what a HUD can do.  It cannot recommend a play nor specifically give real time analysis on a certain situation.  Pretty much limited to straight up statistics.  Nevada gaming commission bans them.

Use of a central database is banned by most if not all.  Sharing of data across HUDs is not allowed.

AI in poker is advanced and there are AI tournaments but not for money.  If you search you can find open source projects.

People doing this are PhD level.  There is a community into this [poker-ai-2016-annual-computer-poker-competition](https://www.pokernews.com/strategy/poker-ai-2016-annual-computer-poker-competition-24246.htm).

Doing it for money is another thing.  Even if the site did not detect the software the betting pattern would flag it.  An AI tournement will rapidly evolve as they get data on each other.

Comment: Did you face with people earning daily bread using bots?

Comment: What if a person would after some time learn from AI this successful betting pattern? Would he also be banned?